# Get Columns Returned from SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to get the columns that a SQL query would return without actually executing a SQL statement?

I looked into using `set showplan_all on` and using the OutputList field, but the results weren't quite what I wanted. I need to get the columns in the correct order and the correct column names (if they are aliased or not).

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

To clarify, here is an example of a query that could run:

```
--log that the user has executed a query
insert into execution_log_table
(timestamp
,user_id
,report_id)
values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,1234
,5678)

select *
from (select column1
,column2
from another_table) tbl
```

I would not want to insert anything into the first table when trying to get the columns returned.

*Note: this is only a simple example, I have some SQL statements that are hundreds of lines of code that do multiple crud operations. I know that I could try to parse the lines of code manually, but my question was directed to a method using SQL servers parser to determine which columns would be returned in the final select statement.

Comment: Is this question related to using SqlBulkCopy by any chance?

Comment: No, I have a reporting application that would benefit from being able to retreive the columns without having to execute the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SET FMTONLY ON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx). It "returns" empty result sets, but shouldn't affect any actual tables:

```
set fmtonly on
go
insert into execution_log_table
([timestamp]
,user_id
,report_id)
values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
,1234
,5678)

select *
from (select column1
,column2
from another_table) tbl
```

---

By the way, *remember* to turn it off before using the same connection for any other activity (using `SET FMTONLY OFF` in its own batch), otherwise you can confuse yourself for a while. (As I did when trying to create tables to test your batch of statements, forgetting that the `CREATE TABLE`s themselves would fail silently (with success messages) once `FMTONLY` was on).

---

I've just noticed that this feature seems to be deprecated, and the replacement only allows you to retrieve information concerning the *first* result set. What use is *that* in the face of complex queries?

Comment: I am still using 2008 R2, a version that this is not depreciated in, so this will work great for me (atleast for the foreseable future). This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible but you can certainly do something like

```
  select <column list>
    ... blah blah
  where 1=0
```

in order to get the shape of the result set without any results.

You have to execute a query but the execution time would be minimal.

Comment: Of course, the truly trivial solution is to just specify the columns the query puts out.

Comment: This won't work because the SQL code won't be known ahead of time. It may contain several statements that could be inserting/updating data before the final select.

Comment: Can't you factor out the final select?

Comment: The SQL statements I am sending are potentially extremely complex that may involve CTE's, temp tables and sub-queries. To handle all these cases, I would have to write a complex SQL parser to create the document outline. I was hoping to rely on the SQL parser already build into SQL Server to handle this for me.

Comment: Well how about 'select * from (very complex query) t where 1=0.  Give it a try.

Comment: The query can contain statements that make changes to actual tables. Additionally, it can take several minutes to execute, which would not be desirable.

Comment: a `SELECT` that changes the tables' structure - of the tables that it's using - while running? Wow, that sounds like a virus query. Can you post a simplified example? It sounds really interesting.